# Cambridge University speech robot

Tags: audio

Is anyone aware of a German language equivalent resource as this website from the University of Cambridge - a question and answer speech recognition robot in English? - https://speakandimprove.com/

Comment: I know of no such (unpaid) resource. But as an aside: try finding (in Google) the bot you linked, just with general terms. I did not succeed. So thanks for the link!